# How are the functions used in cryptographic hash functions chosen?

Tags: algorithm-design, sha-1, md5, sha-2

I'm learning about cryptographic hash functions and I have some questions about the functions used in the compression function.

MD5 uses the following functions:

$f_{1}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\lor(D\wedge \lnot B)$

$f_{2}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge D)\lor(C\wedge\lnot D)$

$f_{3}(B,C,D)=B\oplus C\oplus D$

$f_{4}(B,C,D)=C\oplus(B\lor\lnot D)$

SHA-1 uses these functions:

$f_{1}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\lor(D\wedge \lnot B)$

$f_{2}(B,C,D)=B\oplus C\oplus D$

$f_{3}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\lor(B\wedge D)\lor(C\wedge D)$

$f_{4}(B,C,D)=B\oplus C\oplus D$

SHA-2 uses these functions:

$f_{1}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\lor(D\wedge \lnot B)$

$f_{2}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\oplus(B\wedge D)\oplus(C\wedge D)$

I am wondering how these functions were chosen.

I know that XOR is very effective at mixing the bits of input, but I don't know why a function like $(B\wedge C)\oplus(B\wedge D)\oplus(C\wedge D)$ (SHA-2) is more effective than $(B\wedge C)\lor(B\wedge D)\lor(C\wedge D)$ (SHA-1).

Could someone clarify why certain functions perform better? And how the specific functions were chosen.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The functions considered are binary functions of 3 bits to 1 bit (extended to bit vectors, that is [bitwise functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)). There are $2^{(2^3)}=256$ such functions.

All the functions considered are *balanced*; that is, there is an equal number of input combinations for which the function outputs 0 and for which the function outputs 1. That reduces the number of functions to $8!/(4!)^2=70$.

Aggregating balanced functions identical within the $3!=6$ orders and the $2^3=8$ polarities of the $3$ inputs leaves only $6$ classes (see final section); keeping the lexicographically first function in each class:

```
    z   y   x           g0      g1      g2      g3      g4      g5
    0   0   0           0       0       0       0       0       0
    0   0   1           0       0       0       0       0       1
    0   1   0           0       0       0       0       1       1
    0   1   1           0       1       1       1       1       0
    1   0   0           1       0       1       1       1       1
    1   0   1           1       1       0       1       1       0
    1   1   0           1       1       1       1       0       0
    1   1   1           1       1       1       0       0       1
```

Of these, it is excluded `g0` and `g4` since at least one of their input has no influence on the output. The other four functions exhibit properties that tend to be good for [diffusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_and_diffusion#Definition):

- for any of their input fixed to either polarity, the output is non-constant when we vary the other inputs;
- any of their input influences the output for at least two of the four combinations of the other inputs.

These surviving functions are:

- `g1` [Majority](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/boolean_algebra/majority_function), used for $f_3$ of SHA-1 and $f_2$ of SHA-2 (which turn out to be identical)
- `g2` Choice, used for $f_1$ and $f_2$ of MD5, $f_1$ of SHA-1, $f_1$ of SHA-2; this function is also called Select, or [Digital Multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer#Digital_multiplexers) (input `x` being `1` or `0` chooses which of `y` or `z` is the output);
- `g3`, used (within order and inversion of inputs) for $f_4$ of MD5; as noted in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41295/555#comment94219_41297), that function $(x\wedge y)\oplus z$ is also the [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate#Universality_and_Toffoli_gate)'s third output;
- `g5` [Parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function), used for $f_3$ of MD5, $f_2$ and $f_4$ of SHA-1.

Addition per [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41295/555#comment94191_41297): `g1` and `g2` additionally have the property that any of their input influences the output for at most three of the four combinations of the other inputs; or, in other words, are not fully linear w.r.t. any of their input. This is desirable in some sense, as too much linearity opens to some differential attacks. This might be why `g1` and `g2` are preferred to `g3` and `g5` in SHA-2.

---

A [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/41295/555#comment94316_41297) asks for the derivation of classes of balanced functions of 3 bits to 1 identical within order and polarity of inputs. We'll represent a function by an 8-bit value $b_{000}\,b_{001}\,b_{010}\,b_{011}\,b_{100}\,b_{101}\,b_{110}\,b_{111}$ giving the output $b_{zyx}$ for the 8 combinations of the 3 inputs $z\,y\,x$.

Balanced functions have $b_{000}+b_{001}+b_{010}+b_{011}+b_{100}+b_{101}+b_{110}+b_{111}=4$. We scan them in lexicographic order (equivalently, numerical order when using big-endian convention); if not excluded, that's the function representative of a new class, and we exclude the functions obtainable from that by permutation of inputs, or changing the polarity of inputs. We can do this by considering any of the 6 following transformations applied, or not (there's some redundancy in applying the 64 combinations and many functions are excluded multiple times, but it does not harm):

- turning output to $b_{000}\,b_{010}\,b_{001}\,b_{011}\,b_{100}\,b_{110}\,b_{101}\,b_{111}$ (exchanging $x$ and $y$)
- turning output to $b_{000}\,b_{001}\,b_{100}\,b_{101}\,b_{010}\,b_{011}\,b_{110}\,b_{111}$ (exchanging $y$ and $z$)
- turning output to $b_{000}\,b_{100}\,b_{010}\,b_{110}\,b_{001}\,b_{101}\,b_{011}\,b_{111}$ (exchanging $z$ and $x$)
- turning output to $b_{001}\,b_{000}\,b_{011}\,b_{010}\,b_{101}\,b_{100}\,b_{111}\,b_{110}$ (complementing $x$)
- turning output to $b_{010}\,b_{011}\,b_{000}\,b_{001}\,b_{110}\,b_{111}\,b_{100}\,b_{101}$ (complementing $y$)
- turning output to $b_{100}\,b_{101}\,b_{110}\,b_{111}\,b_{000}\,b_{001}\,b_{010}\,b_{011}$ (complementing $z$)

We first get `00001111` = `g0`, and exclude `00110011`, `01010101`, `10101010`, `11001100`, `11110000`; then get `00010111` = `g1`, and exclude `00101011`, `01001101`, `01110001`, `10001110`, `10110010`, `11010100`, `11101000`; and so on. In the end, there are only 6 classes.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a source where these 4 possible functions are derived or explained? I can find the parity function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_function), the majority function [here](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/boolean_algebra/majority_function), but I can't find anything about the choice and last function. And shouldn't "choice, used for ..., $f_{2}$ of SHA-1", be "choice, used for ..., $f_{1}$ of SHA-1"?

Comment: You mention that `any of their input influences the output for at least two of the four combinations of the other inputs`, but I believe there is also an advantage to have that `any of their input influences the output for at most three of the four combinations of the other inputs`. Otherwise the function could be rewritten as one input XOR'ed with an unbalanced or linear function of the other two inputs. (I don't know for sure, but I guess that's why parity is not used for SHA-2).

Comment: MD5's $f_4 = C\oplus(B\lor\lnot D)$ is somewhat similar to the [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate)'s third output of $C\oplus(B\land A)$

Comment: Could you show in more detail how you aggregated the identical functions, leaving only $6$ classes? That's the last thing I don't comprehend.