# Why do the boolean functions used in cryptographic hashfunctions have 3 inputs (and not more)?

Tags: algorithm-design, sha-2

I'm learning about cryptographic hash functions and know why certain boolean functions were chosen to be used in the compression function of cryptographic hash functions ([older question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41295/how-are-the-functions-used-in-cryptographic-hash-functions-chosen)).

Hash functions like MD5, SHA-1 and SHA-2 all use boolean function with three inputs. However, SHA-2 uses two functions per round.

SHA-2 uses the following functions in every round:

$f_{1}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\lor(D\wedge \lnot B)$

$f_{2}(B,C,D)=(B\wedge C)\oplus(B\wedge D)\oplus(C\wedge D)$

I do not understand why boolean functions with three inputs are used. Why not use a boolean function with 4, 5 or 6 inputs? Why does SHA-2 use two three valued functions per round, why not one six valued function? If the functions are balanced, good for diffusion and not fully linear, it should not make a difference.

Comment: Strictly speaking these are vector boolean functions (vector input, vector output) of the form $$f:\mathbb{F}_2^{3m}\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2^m,$$ where $m=32.$ One plausible reason may be the difficulty of analysing vector boolean functions more than three inputs.

Comment: This question should be closed, because there is no clear answer why this and not a different design was chosen (thus making it opinion-based).

Comment: This question is not almost entirely based on opinions, but instead requires facts, references, or specific expertise. Just because my question might not have a clear answer, does not mean it is opinion-based.

Comment: Agreed. The question is clear and objective, even if clear and objective answers may be difficult.